# Android: after SQLite database has data that is deleted how do I confirm database is empty?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am new to SQLite and am struggling to test for database being empty.  I have a RecyclerView list populated with CardViews.  The data for each CardView comes from a user input UI that updates a SQLite database.  The input is a simple "Name" EditText.  So if the user inputs two Names, then I will have two CardViews in the RecyclerView list and two rows in the database.  If the user then deletes both CardViews, the database should be updated and will then be empty.

How do I check that the database is empty?  I need a row count of zero or a similar indicator that shows that the database is empty.  The count at zero or the indicator at zero will then allow me to switch to a different layout for the ReyclerView list as I need to update the list to show a default layout of zero CardViews since the user has deleted both CardViews by virtue of deleting the two Names from the original two rows in the database.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
Boolean isdbempty= mCursor.getCount()>0 ? false:true;
mCursor.close();
```

Comment: So this says  Move the cursor to the first row of the database table.  Then if the row count is zero return true?

Comment: No , you don't need to move cursor to first . moveToFirst() is to iterate over cursor from beginning , getCount() method will return row count.

Comment: sorry that is what I meant.  the cursor moves to the beginning and counts the rows.  so do I have it correct that the Boolean returns true if the row count is zero?

Comment: Do I need to add this:  mCursor.close();

Answer (score 1):

Check if Table is empty or not.Take count of table rows.

```
public int getProfilesCount() { 
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
int cnt = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return cnt;}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  Closing cursor avoids memory leak?

Comment: No Idea But it's recommended to close the cursor when you are done.

Comment: Ok.  Have you ever used getTaskCount and DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries instead of getProfilesCount?

Comment: getProfilesCount is just method name.you can have anything here.method is just to count no of rows in table

Comment: Ok sorry, it's late here and I didn't notice that at first. So is the rawQuery efficient because it doesn't load all of the rows.  I'm wondering if rawQuery is better than DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries that some other have recommended using.

Comment: DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries is now deprecated.you can use above method.check documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
Boolean isdbempty;
if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
 {   
 isdbempty= true;
 } else
{  
isdbempty= false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can try that.  Does the rawQuery avoid loading all of the rows so it is very efficient?

Comment: Also, don't you need to have "getCount()" or similar after "moveToFirst()"?